# Extra parameters using Autocomplete like Google jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant figure out this

Im using the plugin from http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete/. I need to send an extra parameter to the server to display the colony according to the zipcode for filtering. But I'm not able to get the value. My source code is as follows:

```
$('#colony').autocomplete({
    source: [
        {
            url: "PROV_getColony.ashx?q=%QUERY%" + "&zipCode=" + 
            $("#zipcode").val(),
            type: 'remote',
            minLength: 2
        }
    ]

});
```

`$("#zipcode").val()` is always empty. If I use an alert outside the function, then the value is returned though.

What am I missing?

Comment: The $("#zipcode").val() is being executed right-away when you defining the source - assuming at that moment it is an empty value. If you want to get it dynamically you can use the replace method (http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete/#replace) to modify the URL before it is being sent.

Comment: Ok I get it. Im gonna take a look. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've taken a look to the replace function but I don't know where to define it. Can you give a hand ? Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation you can use the replace option method ([xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete/#replace](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete/#replace)) to modify the URL before it is being sent:

```
$('#colony').autocomplete({
    source: [
        {
            url: "PROV_getColony.ashx?q=%QUERY%" + "&zipCode=%ZIPCODE%"
            type: 'remote',
            minLength: 2
        }
    ],
    replace: function( url,query ){
      return url.replace('%QUERY%', encodeURIComponent(query)).replace('%ZIPCODE%', $("#zipcode").val());
    }
});
```